# where fcntl saves locking information

Tags: linux, locking, multiprocessing, fcntl

I wonder to understand where fcntl c++ function saves information about locked files. I know that it saves some information on /proc/locks , but fcntl identify lock even if it locked by another host

In my first host I locked some file By F_WRLCK.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
main() {

    int fd;
    struct flock lock;
    lock.l_type=F_WRLCK;
    lock.l_start=0;
    lock.l_whence= SEEK_SET;
    lock.l_len=0;
    printf("open %d\n",fd=open("/u/embedit/places/scratch/gtevos/ts16nxq42p11assrl16kaa03/ts16nxq42p11assrl16kaa.cpj", O_RDWR ));
    int rc = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock);
    std::cout<<rc<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>fd;

}
```

When I am traying to lock the same file on my second host by F_RDONLY it doesn't work.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
main() {
    int fd;
    struct flock lock;
    lock.l_type=F_RDLCK;
    lock.l_start=0;
    lock.l_whence= SEEK_SET;
    lock.l_len=0;

    printf("open %d\n",fd=open("/u/embedit/places/scratch/gtevos/ts16nxq42p11assrl16kaa03/ts16nxq42p11assrl16kaa.cpj", O_RDONLY ));
    int rc = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock);
    std::cout<<rc<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>fd;

}
```

I just want to understand which mechanism is used that provide ability to right identify locks.